# How to remove whitespaces in individual list elements in nested lists from a text file?

Tags: python, list, whitespace, strip, txt

I'm really struggling with this one, any help would be appreciated. Trying to get rid of whitespaces around individual list elements. I have tried putting the strip() in various places but I can't figure out how to get it to work properly. :

```
DATAFILE = "unit-patterns.txt"

with open (DATAFILE, "r") as file:
    pattern_strings = []
    pattern_lists1 = []
    pattern_lists = []
    ex_whtspc_lst = []

    for line in file:
        pattern_strings.append(line.split("\t"))   

for index in pattern_strings:      
    pattern_lists1.append(index[0])

for ele in pattern_lists1:
    pattern_lists.append(ele.split("+"))
    
print(str(pattern_lists[0:5]).strip())
```

I get whitespaces around each list element like this:

"[-CITS2224-1-]" - dashes to indicate whitespaces

[Text file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-VNDUQ88xN0dZFIbo8usSDX0JG3deBHG/view?usp=sharing)
[Expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vzsIN.png)

Comment: Please share the exact file content input, and the expected output . For now that is unclear what is missing

Comment: Open your text file in notepad - pretty sure your source data already contains the spaces and brackets.

Comment: Apologies, added the txt file and expected output image.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are facing is that the [`.strip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) method "returns a copy of the string with the leading and trailing characters removed".

In your example, in the `[ CITS2224 1 ]` string, the leading character is `[` and the trailing character is `]`. This causes a regular `.strip()` call to return the string unmodified.

If you pass the `[]`  characters to the `.strip()` call, as suggested by @Tranbi, it will work correctly. Why? This will make python strip any leading and trailing `[]`  characters until a different character is encountered.

Keep in mind that `.strip("[] ")` won't strip the brackets or whitespaces from inside the string, for example `[ foo [] bar ]` - you will get `foo [] bar` instead. Again, this is because `.strip()` considers only the characters passed in the argument (or whitespace if no arguments). If it encounters a character outside of it's interest, processing is stopped.

Comment: Yeah, I'm trying to remove the whitespaces in between the brackets for each element in the lists. 
Are there other methods I can do so?

Comment: If you want to remove whitespaces from the string, in general, use [`.replace(" ", "")`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace). This will remove whitespace anywhere in the string.